# Question on the 2020 RMO.

Tags: contest-math

In the “expression”
each of the twelve @ symbols is replaced with either $\times$ or $÷$ such that the value of the resulting
expression is an integer.

1@2@3@4@5@6@7@8@9@10@11@12@13

Find the greatest common factor of all such integer values.

Comment: ya sorry its my first time using this site. Sorry Ill change it

Comment: None of 7,11,13 can be preceded by a $\div$ sign.  The situation with 3,9 is more complicated, because of the presence of 12 and 6.  Similarly, the situation with 5 is more complicated because of the 10.  The only approach that comes to my mind is to compute the prime factorization of all 12 numbers $> 1$, and then consider that if (for example) $\alpha$ is the largest exponent such that $p^\alpha$ divides the *result*, where $p$ is a prime, then $\alpha$ **must be** non-negative, so that the *result* is an integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First every such integer is divisible by $7, 11, 13$.

Highest power of $2$ of $13!$ is even, so you need to find an integer product such that it's odd. This can be easily done.

Then the highest power of $3$ of $13!$ is odd, so you need to find an integer product such that it's divisible by $3$ but not by $9$. This is easy too.

The highest power of $5$ of $13!$ is $2$. It's easy to find one integer product that's not divisible by $5$.

Therefore the $\gcd$ of all integer products is $3\times 7 \times 11 \times 13 = 3003$.

Comment: +1 : nice......

Comment: Could you expand on why you drop 5 when calculating gcd?

Comment: @bajun65537 One of the integers is $10/5$ times everything else, which is not divisible by $5$.

Comment: Haha of course! Cheers.